# What is the proper substitution for this integration?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Evaluate the integral $$\int_{D} \frac{x}{y} d x d y$$ $D=\left\{(x, y): x^{2}+y^{2}<4, x y>\sqrt{3}, x>0\right\}$

$$\int_{D} \frac{x}{y} d x d y = \int_{0}^{4} \frac{1}{y}d y\int_{0}^\sqrt{4-y^2}x dx-\int_0^2 \frac{1}{y}dy\int_0^{\frac{\sqrt 4}{y}}x dx$$

I can't find the correct substitution: both direct integration and polar coordinates lead to "$y=\log0$".

Comment: Post your attempt with polar coordinates, it should have worked.

Comment: Why are you not setting this up as a single iterated integral? Of course you should never start with $y=0$. Indeed, in the region you have $1\le y\le \sqrt3$.

Comment: @TedShifrin thank you, That's surely correct, but I can't find $y\geq 1$ from the domain.

Comment: First things first. Where do the two curves intersect? What algebra have you done? You get a quadratic equation to solve for $y^2$.

Comment: $xy>\sqrt{3} \implies x^2>\frac{3}{y^2}$ and $\frac{3}{y^2}+y^2 < 4$. Then I substitute $y^2=t$ and solve it?

Comment: Yes, just solve it. Alternatively, where are the intersection points of the two equations of degree two $x^2+y^2=2^4$ and $xy=3$? (We expect (at most) four, Bezout. We can easily see them all with bare eyes, without solving anything.) So which is the shape of $D$ (inside the open disk centered in the origin with radius two)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your limits for $y$ is incorrect. As $xy \gt \sqrt3$, $y$ cannot be zero. See the shaded region in the sketch.

[image]

Intersection of the circle $x^2+y^2=4$ and curve $xy = \sqrt3$ will be given by

$x^2 + \frac{3}{x^2} = 4 \implies x = 1, y = \sqrt3, x = \sqrt3, y = 1$ (as $x\gt0$, we have only considered positive values of $x$).

So the integral should be $\displaystyle \int_1^\sqrt3 \int_{\sqrt3/y}^\sqrt{4-y^2} \frac{x}{y} \ dx \ dy$